# Finishing off a For Loop function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having a real problem finishing off this For Loop function.. basically when a player reaches a certain score, they get a certain cash amount..

Here the variables..

```
CashThresholds = [500000, 1000000, 1500000, 2000000, 2500000, 3000000, 3500000, 4000000, 4500000, 5000000];

TheCashValues = [0.50, 1.00, 1.50, 2.00, 2.50, 3.00, 3.50, 4.00, 4.50, 5.00];
```

Here's the rest..

```
var TheCashValues = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < CashThresholds.length; i++) {                
    if (CashThresholds[i] > TheScore) {         
        TheCashValues = CashThresholds[i];
    }
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Quite clearly, its 'send me the codez'

Comment: @AmirAfghani: That doesn't seem like an entirely fair assessment. He provided the code he has so far. Only problem is that he didn't articulate the issue explicitly.

Comment: My question is simple.. to award the player with a cash amount on reaching the relevant score (CashThreshold) within the game. So, if the player reaches 500000 points they are awarded with 0.50, if they reach 2500000 points they are awarded 2.50.

Comment: When you write TheCashValues = 0; it wipes out the array. May be for starters change that line to TheCashValue = 0; without the s at the end.

Comment: Done that (TheCashValue = 0) -- still doesn't work.. changes the cash amount from "0" to "5000000" on first click.

Comment: On the very first iteration of the loop, if (CashThresholds[i] > TheScore), you're asking if 500000 is greater than TheScore, which it probably is, so the next line executes and TheCashValue takes 0.50 right away. Use a debugger to check the state of variables as the code is running.

Comment: OK but why out of all the CashThreshold amounts is 5000000 coming up?

Comment: Went on degugging, the variable "CashThreshold" increases fine when running F10 etc, but the "TheCashValue" remains at 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to set TheCashValues to the bonus the user receives once they surpass a certain score, you should loop backwards over the CashThresholds until you reach a threshold that a user has surpassed, and award them the corresponding amount of points.

The `break;` stops the loop from continuing once we find the highest award the user has achieved.

```
var award =0;
//TheCashValues =0;
for (var i = CashThresholds.length-1; i>=0; i--){
    if (TheScore > CashThresholds[i]){
        award = TheCashValues[i];
        break;
    }
}
console.log(award);
```

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Sure, when the game runs using that code, the Cash amount goes to 0, which is fine, but when the player, i.e. me in this case reaches the first threshold of 50000 points, the Cash amount doesn't change.

Comment: You are setting TheCashValues to 0 before the loop and then trying to access it within the loop as the amount to give the player. I created a separate variable, award, to keep track of the bonus to award the player, and commented out the line that's sets the award amounts to zero.

Comment: If that is the case, something is wrong outside of the code you have provided for us. Perhaps you could post more of the surrounding code or create a JSFiddle for us to work with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68991/discussion-between-midae-and-ateich).